# CSS "page-break-after" on an undefined div

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I have a search engine that produces a variety of widgets (each in it's own div), each time a different amount of widgets.

When we print the results page widgets can be cut in the middle by a page break, and i would like for each widget to be inside a page and not cut by the page break.

We tried:

```
@media print {
    .widget {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

And it cut all of the widget, each for a different page, which is not what we want. We want the page break to happen only if it's necesary. 
Obviously we don't want to make the page-break for a specific widget because we don't know which one will be the one that has to be cut.

We also tried:

```
@media print {
    .widget {page-break-after: avoid;}
}
```

And it also didn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it you want to use:

```
.widget {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

That will push any of your widgets that span the page down to the next one.